# How to retrieve rows with particular number of different column values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am implementing an exam portal. I have teacher and student as users.

Teachers generate question set for particular subject for taking exam. He has 4 options based on exam full marks ( 20 marks, 50 marks, 80 marks and 100 marks ), duration is also fixed during marks selection as 30 min, 60 min, 90 min, and 120 mins.

I have a **question** table. That has field for **question, answer and level**(Easy, Medium, Hard). Easy question 1 marks, Medium level question 2 marks and Hard level question 3 marks.

Any number of questions could be added to the set by teacher. And questions will be fetched randomly from database. Also each student should get 6 easy, 4 medium and 2 hard level question in a set of 20 marks, i.e. total 12 questions to be fetched randomly following criteria of levels. Similarly, for 50 marks set, 15 EASY level, 10 MEDIUM level and 3 HARD level questions have to be fetched and so on.

Please avoid all other conditions you think must be present and help me with forming an mysql query or just  help me with some clues of what sql clause should I use.

Comment: Can you share the table structure and sample data along with the required output

Comment: I have two tables, 1st is questions_set(id, status, duration, marks, faculty_id, subject_id, class, board) and other is questions(id, set_id, question, answer, level)

Suppose I create a set with values (1, 'inactive', 30, 20, 'f_1', 'sub1', 'VIII', 'ICSE' )
Then all the students under faculty with id 'f_1' studying sub1 in class VIII and board ICSE gets to appear for that exam when teacher activates the link. And teacher may activate link only when he creates 6 easy level questions, 4 medium level questions and 2 hard level questions.
question table have values like (1,1,'q1','a1','Easy')

Comment: Someone should determine the percentage of easy, medium, hard answers that makes up the questions of a set. Is it fixed as 30% easy, 40% medium, and 30% hard? Because that's what I noticed in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a [union select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) two times additionally to first query so each select gets a set by question level.

Comment: How are you planning to select particular number of hard, easy and medium level question?

Comment: each select has their own WHERE statements. the union makes sure to join the results as long as they have the same amount of columns.

Answer (score -1):

From just the title, I would guess you are looking for

```
HAVING COUNT(col) = 7
```